# How to overlap the heatmap with scatter in python?

Tags: python, visualization, heatmap, scatter-plot

I have two dataframes, one for heatmap with size (189, 52), the index represents the height, the column name represents the date, the other size (1542, 1), the index represents the date and the value represents the height, scatter data starts from 2023-4-14 15:26:00, heatmap data starts from 2023-4-14 15:40:00, the interval of scatter is 20s, the interval of heatmap is 10mins, the height of two dataframes have same standard, however the date of scatter is much wider than the heatmap, how can i overlap the heatmap with scatter points?

```
fig, ax_heatmap = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.heatmap(windSpeedData, cmap='viridis', cbar_kws={'label': 'Wind Speed'}, ax=ax_heatmap)
ax_heatmap.set_xticks(test.columns\[::43\])
ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels(test.columns\[::43\], rotation=45)
ax_heatmap.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(windSpeedData.index), 20))
ax_heatmap.set_yticklabels(windSpeedData.index\[::20\])

ax_heatmap.invert_yaxis()

ax_scatter = ax_heatmap.inset_axes(\[0, 0, 1, 1\], zorder=-1, transform=ax_heatmap.transAxes)
scatter_plot = sns.scatterplot(data=vData, x=vData.index, y=vData\['height'\], size=marker_size, ax=ax_scatter)
scatter_plot.set_xticks(vData.index\[::42\])
scatter_plot.set_xticklabels(vData.index\[::42\], rotation=90)
scatter_plot.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(windSpeedData.index), 20))
scatter_plot.set_yticklabels(windSpeedData.index\[::20\])
scatter_plot.yaxis.set_visible(False)
```

[image]

```
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

windSpeedData is the dataset for heatmap, the vData is for the scatter plot.